# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113 2 App not installed

Tags: lightroom

com.adobe.lrmobile_8.3.3-608033000_2arch_2dpi_14lang_a10aca2835a3ef64a4ce2d85abddd560_apkmirror.com.apkm
1   INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113
2   App not installed
I need you at any cost, please help me.

[text](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.